# Как сделать универсальную логику чтения в go(чтоб stdin и файл читать не меняя кода)?

Tags: golang

Я хочу чтоб функция читала из потока ввода и не зависела от того, что в нее передано(stdin или файл). Но при передаче в функцию потока ввода, она работает неправильно и не блокируется на чтении.

```
func testRead(reader io.Reader)  {
    var test []byte
    _, _ = reader.Read(test)
    println(test)
}
```

Comment: А зачем ей быть блокирующей, каков смысл сего требования? Опять же, если вы запускаете эту функцию через отдельный goroutine, то она тоже будет не-блокирующей.

Comment: Вы можете использовать [`bufio.ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) - эта функция гарантированно блокируется до тех пор, пока не встретит конец строки.

Comment: Что значит «блокируется на чтении»?  Вы ей данные как скармливаете?